# Sending an Ajax request from a jsp page to a spring Controller

Tags: ajax, jsp, spring-mvc, arraylist

I am trying to make an ajax call from a jsp page using the spring MVC framework to fetch some data from the server but I am getting the following error.

```
10-Dec-2015 11:53:05.349 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-14] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/EIMEnterprise/[object%20Object]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'
```

No matter what I have as my URL parameter for my $.get call, it seems to attach an [object%20Object]] value at the end. Here is my Ajax Controller Class

```
@Controller
public class AjaxController {

@RequestMapping(value="/viewhiers.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ArrayList<HierarchyBean> getHiersViaAjax(@RequestParam("versionID") int versionID) {
    //return an arraylist of HierarchyBean

}

}
```

Below is my web.xml file

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee               http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
 version="3.1">

<display-name>EIMEnterprise</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And below is my jsp page with the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#versiontab tr td').click(function() {
                //alert("Hello");
                //highlight the current row and disable highlight on the other rows
                $(this).closest("tr").addClass('highlightblue').siblings().removeClass('highlightblue');

                //make an ajax call to populate the hierarchies
                $.get({
                    url: '/EIMEnterprise/viewhiers.html?versionID=1',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert("success");
                        /*
                        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                            alert(index + " " + value);
                        });*/
                    }
                });
            });

        });

    </script>
```

And here is my spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<!--Scan this package for any controller annotations-->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.eimenterprise.controllers" />

<!--Used for using pathvariable with map-->


<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong as it seems to append an object value at the end of the urL instead of sending it to the correct controller and thus cannot find the mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was passing the parameters wrong in $.get. This is resolved.

Should use $.get in the following way.

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```